# jQuery Mobile - loading indicator over specified listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, loading, indicator

I have a little problem with jQuery mobile. On my mobile page I have 3 areas which are loaded asynchronously and I want to show loading indicator over every of those areas. Of course I can keep global loading indicator until every area is loaded but it's not the point. I want to use jQM built in functionality if possible, if not - it's not a problem to create new one. Is there only global-page loading indicator in jQuery?

Comment: I'm afraid there is only a global one, had to create my own local ones myself as well

Comment: Finally I've added image of loading indicator with class "ui-icon" to the callapsible list (which I want to load asynchronously) and after loading data I simply remove that image from DOM. It looks and works quite well.